# two dimensional unit ball as the intersection of a collection of closed half spaces.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, convex-geometry

I am trying to represent the two dimensional closed unit ball, $\mathbb{B} \in \mathbb{R^2}$ as the intersection of a collection of closed half spaces, and find the half spaces explicitly.

Definitions that I believe I have to use are the followings.

Given a nonzero vector $p\in \mathbb{R^2}$ and a real number $\alpha$, 
Hyperplane: $H=\{ x\in \mathbb{R^2} | p \cdot x = \alpha\}$

Its associated closed half spaces: $H^+=\{ x\in \mathbb{R^2} | p\cdot x \geq  \alpha\}$ and $H^-=\{ x\in \mathbb{R^2} | p\cdot x \leq \alpha\}$

I tried to make a line that has a intersecting point on the unit circle. But I am not sure if I am right.

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 1):

For every point $y$ on the boundary sphere (i.e. $\|y\| = 1$), the halfspace
$$\{x \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \cdot y \le 1\}$$
contains the unit ball, by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality (if $\|x\| \le 1$, then $x \cdot y \le \|x\| \|y\| = \|x\| \le 1$). Thus,
$$B[0; 1] \subseteq \bigcap_{y \in S[0; 1]} \{x \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \cdot y \le 1\} \tag{$\star$}.$$
On the other hand, if $x \notin B[0;1]$, i.e. $\|x\| > 1$, and we let $y = x/\|x\|$, then
$$x \cdot y = x \cdot x / \|x\| = \|x\|^2 / \|x\| = \|x\| > 1,$$
hence $x \notin \{x \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x \cdot y \le 1\}$. Hence, we get equality in $(\star)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it really helped me a lot. By the way, does S mean the boundary of the unit circle ?

Comment: Yes, $S[0; 1]$ refers to the sphere of the unit ball (i.e. the unit circle).